# How to calculate between two String method in java

Tags: java

I'm writing a small program to check the fuel status. This method is to show the fuel level before stop.

```
public String fuelLevelStart(String AccountID, String DeviceID, long time)
    {
        DBCamera objcmr = new  DBCamera();
        String str="-";
        double fuelStart=0;
        try
        {

            fuelStart= objcmr.FuelBeforeStop(AccountID,DeviceID,time);
            if(fuelStart==0.0)
            {
                str="-";
            }
            else
            {
                fuelStart= round(fuelStart, 2);
                str=Double.toString(fuelStart);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        return str;
    }
```

and here is to check after the vehicle stops:

```
public String fuelLevelEnd(String AccountID, String DeviceID, long time, double fuel)
    {
        DBCamera objcmr = new  DBCamera();
        String str="-";
        double fuelStart=0;
        try
        {

            List<Double> list = objcmr.FuelAfterStop(AccountID,DeviceID,time);
            if(list.size()<1)
            {
                if(fuel<=0)
                    str="-";
                else
                    str=Double.toString(round(fuel, 2));
            }  
            else
            {           
                fuelStart= list.get(0);
                if(fuelStart==0)
                    str="-";
                else
                    str=Double.toString(round(fuelStart, 2));
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            str="aa";
        }

        return str;
    }
```

my problem is how to calculate this two index to show total the fuel that  was used. The algorithm is easy: minus start level by end level, however I am confused about the way to get the final result from these two methods. Can someone give me any idea?

Comment: You should return `double` instead of `String`. Although this will work fine. Just use Double.parseDouble() to convert the string to double and then substract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @Francois-Xavier Laviron's solution, you can solve your problem like this:

```
public double usedFuel(String AccountID, String DeviceID, long time, double fuel){
        Double useFuel = 0.0;
        try{
            useFuel = Double.parseDouble(fuelLevelStart(AccountID, DeviceID, time)) - Double.parseDouble(fuelLevelEnd(AccountID, DeviceID, time, fuel));
            System.out.printf(" ",useFuel);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        return useFuel;
    }
```

if you keep String in your methods.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string results back to doubles with Double.parseDouble(). But first check if the function returned a "-" String, so for example in case of the start fuel you would say something like

```
    if (startFuel.equals("-")) {
        startFuelValue = 0.0;
    }
    else {
        startFuelValue = Double.parseDouble(startFuel);
    }
```

But may I ask, why do your methods return Strings and not doubles?

You should change your fuelLevelStart method to

```
public double fuelLevelStart(String AccountID, String DeviceID, long time){
    //compute the fuel level
    return fuelStart;
}
```

And when you want to print the "-" symbol for fuelStart level 0, just use and if statement.

Comment: because I want to show "-" symbol in case of fuel equal 0

Comment: I would suggest keeping the values as double values, and when you want to print the "-" for fuel equals 0, print it correspondly.

Answer (score 0):

Check if returned values are numbers, and then convert them using Double.parse(String s). Then do the math.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a good reason to store your fuel levels as String, but it a good rule of thumb to keep them in their natural type (say Double) until the need of display and until then throw and catch exceptions when unnatural values occur.

```
    public Double fuelLevelStart(String AccountID, String DeviceID, long time) throws FuelException
    {
        DBCamera objcmr = new  DBCamera();
        String str="-";
        double fuelStart=0;
        try
        {

            fuelStart= objcmr.FuelBeforeStop(AccountID,DeviceID,time);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            throw new FuelException("cannot perform objcmr.FuelBeforeStop");
        }
        if(fuelStart==0.0)
        {
            throw new FuelException("empty");
        }
        fuelStart= round(fuelStart, 2);


        return fuelStart;
    }
```

perform equivalent changes to fuelLevelEnd  and then call

```
...
Double usedFuel;
try{
     usedFuel = fuelLevelStart(AccountID,  DeviceID, time) - fuelLevelEnd(AccountID, DeviceID, time, fuel);
     // display the result for instance:
     System.out.printf("fuel consumption %.2f %n",usedFuel); 

}
catch(FuelException e){
    // display or re-throw more general exception
}
```